# entry-listeners for query-cache in Hazelcast client config

Tags: hazelcast

Hazelcast full client config sample on GitHub defines an entry listener for a query cache, see
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-client/src/main/resources/hazelcast-client-full.xml

I tried it out, but the entry listener registration via xml config seems to be ignored. The programmatic approach using method addEntryListener() of class QueryCache works fine.

In Hazelcast documentation, I cannot find further information for entry listener configuration on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can  provide declarative configfor query cache. Example config will be as below ... client side or server side

```
<map name="myMap">
   <query-caches>
      <query-cache name="myContQueryCache">
         <include-value>true</include-value>
         <predicate type="class-name">com.hazelcast.examples.ExamplePredicate</predicate>
         **<entry-listeners>
             <entry-listener include-value="false" local="false">
            com.yourpackage.MyEntryListener
          </entry-listener>
         </entry-listeners>**
         <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
         <populate>true</populate>
                  <coalesce>false</coalesce>
                  <batch-size>2</batch-size>
                  <delay-seconds>3</delay-seconds>
                  <buffer-size>32</buffer-size>
                  <eviction size="1000" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT" eviction-policy="LFU"/>
                  <indexes>
                         <index ordered="true">...</index>
                  </indexes>
           </query-cache>
    </query-caches>
</map>
```

Entry-Listeners: Adds listeners (listener classes) for your query cache entries.

It is also to note ...

IMap events are reflected in continuous query cache in the same order as they were generated on map entries. Since events are created on entries stored in partitions, ordering of events is maintained based on the ordering within the partition. You can add listeners to capture lost events using EventLostListener and you can recover lost events with the method QueryCache.tryRecover(). Recovery of lost events largely depends on the size of the buffer on Hazelcast members. Default buffer size is 16 per partition; i.e. 16 events per partition can be maintained in the buffer. If the event generation is high, setting the buffer size to a higher number will provide better chances of recovering lost events. You can set buffer size with QueryCacheConfig.setBufferSize(). You can use the following example code for a recovery case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description, Riaz.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not manage to get the declarative approach work.